# Spark AMI for Ubuntu (or maybe Centos) - NOT amazon linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

The spark distribution includes an ec2 launch script that points to a location in github for spark ami's. Unfortunately the ami (only one) is an amazon linux - which is very limited. Specifically the amazon linux ami has limited packages support.

So, if for example I want to get php5.4 (instead of default 5.3) on the amazon linux - no such luck.

Are there any non-amazon linux ami's available for using with the spark-ec2?

Comment: I don't know of any such images, but you can generate your own AMIs easily using Packer and [these scripts](https://github.com/nchammas/spark-ec2/tree/packer/image-build). All you'd have to do is edit [these lines](https://github.com/nchammas/spark-ec2/blob/0f313de64ad9542d1a0f0d6f27131ca4bc01d8c3/image-build/spark-packer-template.json#L5-L6) to specify the base AMIs you want to use.

Comment: Around the 1.4 release time frame I will try to get this merged into `mesos/spark-ec2` so they can be maintained by the community. You can follow the related JIRA here: [SPARK-3821](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3821)

Comment: @NickChammas  Why not make your comments an answer so I can award.

Comment: and btw i had been following your threads on the dev spark ML. you are pretty prolific

Comment: Thank you. :) Let me know if you end up trying the Packer stuff and need pointers. Would be glad to help out.

Comment: I am interested to do so, under the gun for next two months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of an up-to-date set of Spark AMIs apart from the ones [provided by the Spark project](https://github.com/mesos/spark-ec2/tree/branch-1.3/ami-list).

That said, I have developed a way using [Packer](https://packer.io/) to automatically create a set of Spark AMIs from a set of base AMIs and some Bash scripts:

https://github.com/nchammas/spark-ec2/tree/packer/image-build

This is being done as part of [SPARK-3821](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3821).

You'll need to do some work to get this to work with Ubuntu, since the scripts currently assume a `yum`-based Linux distribution.

Basically:

- [These lines](https://github.com/nchammas/spark-ec2/blob/0f313de64ad9542d1a0f0d6f27131ca4bc01d8c3/image-build/spark-packer-template.json#L5-L6) define the base AMIs to build on.
- [These lines](https://github.com/nchammas/spark-ec2/blob/0f313de64ad9542d1a0f0d6f27131ca4bc01d8c3/image-build/spark-packer-template.json#L63-L66) show the scripts that are being run to build the image.
- [These](https://github.com/nchammas/spark-ec2/blob/0f313de64ad9542d1a0f0d6f27131ca4bc01d8c3/image-build/spark-packer-template.json#L23-L31) and [these](https://github.com/nchammas/spark-ec2/blob/0f313de64ad9542d1a0f0d6f27131ca4bc01d8c3/image-build/spark-packer-template.json#L46-L54) lines tell Packer to copy the built AMIs to all EC2 regions. You probably want to change this.

The shortest path to success for you might be to try a CentOS or Fedora base image that has the packages you are looking for. That will minimize the changes you have to make to the Bash scripts.

Around the Spark 1.4 release timeframe (roughly June/July 2015), I will work to have this merged into the main `spark-ec2` repo.